# How to pass TestContext to a method which does not accept the Gin Context as an argument?

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm writing tests for a Gin-Gonic based service. 
I have a handler which does not accept the gin context as a parameter. 
Example:

```
func (h *handler) Handler1(isTrue bool) func(*gin.Context) {

    return func(c *gin.Context) { .. Do Something }
}
```

I want to write the test for this method but I dont know how I should be passing it the mock Gin Context.

If I was doing this for any other method (like the Ping method below) which accepts the Gin Context as an argument, this is how I would be doing it.

```
func (*handler) Ping(c *gin.Context) {
    c.String(http.StatusOK, "Pong")
    c.Writer.WriteHeaderNow()
} // Method
```

In the test:

```
handler := NewHandler()
recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
mockGinContext, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(recorder)
handler.Ping(mockGinContext)
```

For *Handler1*, how should I pass it the TestContext?

Comment: Your function returns a function that accepts a gin context. So pass that context to the returned function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use same strategy in test:

```
var h *handler
h = ... // however you create *handler
recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
mockGinContext, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(recorder)
// note that you will have to know do you want to test both, 
// or just one of the handlers returned from Handler1
h.Handler1(true)(mockGinContext)
h.Handler1(false)(mockGinContext)
```